# How to test routes

Tags: mailgun

I have a webpage that reads webhooks received from mail events and routes

In mailgun I created a subdomain that we actually only use for testing, I can not add MX records to the domain we use.

so for example for my domain "mycompany.com" I have added "testing.mycompany.com"

Now I want to send a mail to "testaccount@testing.mycompany.com" that get forwarded with mailgun routes to my webpage but.

Without being able to add MX records to our main domain, is it possible to configure a solution in mailgun so I can send an email to an unexisting mail "testaccount@testing.mycompany.com" in a newly created subdomain ?